# Cross Site History Manipulation(Checkmarx)

Tags: java, security, checkmarx, secure-coding, secure-random

Does anyone know how to fix the Checkmarx vulnerability -- Cross Site History Manipulation for java based applcations? 
Here is the description provided by Checkmarx scan -- "the method may leak server-side conditional values, enabling user tracking from another website. This may constitute a Privacy Violation."

Here is the related code :

```
if(user is logged in) {
     response.sendRedirect(url);
} else {
     response.sendRedirect(url)
}
```

Upon googling I found some Checkmarx documentation which to suggest to add a  random number to the redirect url. Here is the link to the document : https://www.checkmarx.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/XSHM-Cross-site-history-manipulation.pdf

For e.g :

```
If ( !isAuthenticated)
  Redirect(„Login.aspx?r=‟ + Random())
```

I tried this approach but the Checkmarx scan still show the same vulnerability.Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

XSHM could be a CWE-203 (http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/203.html) from CX documentation.

The problem could be complex or simple. With just your 5 lines we can not said exactly what the good solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Checkmarx is check if your redirect url include some random value. Here are some **random** methods checking by Java/Cx/General/Find_Cross_Site_History_Manipulation_Random:

1. `Random.Next`
2. `Math.random`
3. `Randomizer.*`
4. `Random.nextBytes`